# VS 2015 Update 3 error for deleted copy assignment operator

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015

Following code compiles well on clang-3.8 and gcc 4.9.3.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

class foo 
{
};

class MyVec {
    public:
    MyVec() {}
};

class MyInsert :
    public std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, void, void, void, void>
{
  protected :
    MyVec &fV;

  public :
    explicit MyInsert (MyVec &v) : fV(v) {}

    MyInsert & operator= (void *value)
    {
        return *this;
    }

    MyInsert & operator* ()    { return *this; }
    MyInsert & operator++ ()   { return *this; }
    MyInsert & operator++(int) { return *this; }

};    

class test
{
    public:    
    void method()
    {
        MyVec retv;

        std::vector<const foo*> foovec;
        std::transform(foovec.begin(), foovec.end(),MyInsert(retv),[](const foo*)->void* { return nullptr;});
    }
};

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

However, when compiled on VS 2015 Update 3, it fails with following error message.

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xutility(458): error C2280: 'MyInsert &MyInsert::operator =(const MyInsert &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
test\mytests\main.cpp(33): note: compiler has generated 'MyInsert::operator =' here
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\algorithm(926): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_Iter &std::_Rechecked<_OutIt,_OutIt>(_Iter &,_UIter)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Iter=MyInsert,
            _OutIt=MyInsert,
            _UIter=MyInsert
        ]
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\algorithm(950): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::_Transform_no_deprecate1<const foo**,_OutIt,_Fn1>(_InIt,_InIt,
_OutIt,_Fn1 &,std::input_iterator_tag,std::_Any_tag)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _OutIt=MyInsert,
            _Fn1=test::method::<lambda_45e8626339fc29aadca2bf2dd3420511>,
            _InIt=const foo **
        ]
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\algorithm(960): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::_Transform_no_deprecate<_InIt,_OutIt,_Fn1>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt,
_Fn1 &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _OutIt=MyInsert,
            _InIt=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<const foo *>>>,
            _Fn1=test::method::<lambda_45e8626339fc29aadca2bf2dd3420511>
        ]
test\mytests\main.cpp(45): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::transform<std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<const
foo *>>>,MyInsert,test::method::<lambda_45e8626339fc29aadca2bf2dd3420511>>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt,_Fn1)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _OutIt=MyInsert,
            _InIt=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<const foo *>>>,
            _Fn1=test::method::<lambda_45e8626339fc29aadca2bf2dd3420511>
        ]
        ]
```

I am not able understand why it (VS Compiler) is not able to find the copy assignment operator which takes `void *` and gives back `MyInsert &` when clearly one is explicitly provided.

Digging more into (by following the error message trace)

`c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio14.0\vc\include\xutility`

and

`c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio14.0\vc\include\algorithm`

also made me realize that actual function where `std::transformation` algorithm is invoked, the explicitly provided copy assignment is invoked, after which it enters `_Rechecked` function and it goes into the `xutility` header.

In this function, the copy assignment operator invoked which expects (input as `MyInsert&` and output as `MyInsert&`) and since it doesnt find one, it displays the error message as `attempting to reference...`.

Is this analysis correct ? If not, then why is not able to compile the code which is getting compiled on other major compilers? Perhaps a bug?

P.S

Current work around that I am using is to remove the reference member in `MyInsert` class with non-reference member.

Comment: @Oktalist ah, my bad then!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am not able understand why it (VS Compiler) is not able to find the copy assignment operator which takes `void *` and gives back `MyInsert &` when clearly one is explicitly provided.

An assignment operator that takes a `void*` is not a **copy** assignment operator.

The compiler does attempt to use the copy assignment operator which is *clearly* not provided explicitly. Nor is it provided implicitly, because there is a reference member.

The output iterator must meet the requirements of [*OutputIterator*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/OutputIterator) which must meet the requirements of [*Iterator*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator) Which must meet the requirements of [*CopyAssignable*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable) which unsurprisingly requires you to have a copy assignment operator. Which is something that `MyInsert` lacks.

> why is not able to compile the code which is getting compiled on other major compilers?

While the output iterator must meet the requirements, there is no requirement for the standard library implementation to check that the requirements are met.

Hopefully the formal specification of concepts will be part of the standard in the future to improve the error messages in cases like this.

> Perhaps a bug?

The bug is the missing copy assignment operator in your code. Both VS and the other compilers are standard compliant in this regard.

> Current work around that I am using is to remove the reference member in MyInsert class with non-reference member.

By removing the reference member, you allow the implicit declaration of the copy assignment operator. That's why it works. To keep referring to an object while still keeping the type copy assignable, use a plain pointer instead of a reference.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't find it weird. It's easy to imagine an implementation of `std::transform` that doesn't need to copy assign the output iterator. The call to `std::transform` **c**ould be an error - as in: there is no guarantee that it will work - but I don't think that the standard requires the implementation to check that type requirements are met.

Comment: Yeah I realized that.  The issue I have is the copy constructor should also be deleted so I have not idea how it even calls the function if we stop copy elision.

Comment: I would agree except [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3051bb080f39558e) should fail but it does not.

Comment: @NathanOliver it doesn't prevent implicit copy constructor either.

Comment: @NathanOliver & Oktalist. Indeed, my stressing move construction was misleading, since reference member prevents neither implicit move nor copy constructor - I didn't remember that. References aren't assignable, so that's what they prevent - copy(and move) assignment.

Comment: @Oktalist Dag nab it.  You are correct.  I am so used to dealing with a member that has a deleted copy c'tor which in turn deletes the class copy c'tor that I forgot references do not do that.

Comment: The requirement [*Iterator*](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements#iterator.iterators) does state that an iterator must satisfy *CopyAssignable*. Does that mean its underlying type must be *CopyAssignable* as well? I don't see a particular statement in the requirement.

Comment: @PHD What do you mean by "underlying type"?

Comment: For example, `vector<T>::iterator` is defined as [`__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<pointer, vector>`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_vector.h#L451) in libstdc++. An underlying type means `vector<T>::value_type` in this case.

Comment: @PHD `value_type` isn't required to be copyassignable by the iterator concept.

Comment: What I meant is that *Iterator* also requires *CopyConstructible*, but the following [code](https://godbolt.org/z/e3rfo49GT) compiles fine when a copy constructor is missing. When there are two requirements (*CopyConstructible*, *CopyAssignable*) present, it is strange that only one of them is taken into consideration for `value_type`. I'm asking if this only applies to `iterator` instead. If so, is it necessary for `value_type` to have a copy assignment operator?

Comment: Thank you. It seems that the code I provided fails because [`std::copy`](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.copy) requires a given type to have a copy assignment operator. I understood that the value type of an iterator need not have a copy assignment operator